# gnu ld (mac) not working, linker command fail with error code 1

Tags: c++, macos, linker, ld, cudd

I have the following problem with my ld.

```
$ ld
ld: warning: -arch not specified
ld: warning: -macosx_version_min not specified, assuming 10.9
ld: no object files specified for inferred architecture x86_64
```

What shall I do?

I got the following errors when I compile CUDD:

```
libmtr.a ../st/libst.a ../util/libutil.a ../epd/libepd.a  -lm
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_edata", referenced from:
      _util_print_cpu_stats in libutil.a(cpu_stats.o)
  "_end", referenced from:
      _util_print_cpu_stats in libutil.a(cpu_stats.o)
  "_etext", referenced from:
      _util_print_cpu_stats in libutil.a(cpu_stats.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [nanotrav] Error 1
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

PS: I am using

```
$ xcodebuild -version
Xcode 7.1
Build version 7B91b
```

my ld is `/usr/bin/ld`.

Comment: In the first case `$ ld`, the linker is just saying you have invoked it
without telling it do anything (no commandline options). In the second
case, "compiling CUDD" (actually, attempting to link something with CUDD libraries), you appear to be trying to link using a linker script that does not define  `_edata`, `_end` and `_etext`, but until you post the failing linker command and its complete output we can only guess why.

Comment: The changes suggested in this post work for me. I use g++ on mac. Check this [link](http://www.technical-recipes.com/2011/setting-up-the-cu-decision-diagram-cudd-package-for-windows/)